# Setting a reply-to address for an email

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Marketing Cloud, I want to configure a Reply-To address for a sender and "bypass" Reply Mail Management.

How can this be done? I'm expecting there to be a field for a "Reply To" address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the Reply Mail Management settings by using Sender Profiles. Help on how to create these are [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/#How_to_Create_a_Sender_Profile).

The steps are:

1. Create a new Sender Profile
2. Create a new Delivery Profile
3. Create a new Send Classification

[image: You select a send classification, together with content information and audience information, when you define a message send by creating a message interaction. *Source: Exact Target Documentation*]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SarojBera, I've updated the submitted answer to include high-level steps.